# Fastest way to slice a list with upper bound not in the list

Tags: python, list

Let's say that we have a huge sorted list with integers. What is the fastest way to slice this list using an upper bound that is not in the list?

For example, let's say that our list is:

```
l=list(range(0,1000000, 2))
```

(this is a simple example, the list could be of any length and with no specific interval, so it cannot be related with some range)

And we want to get a slice, with items smaller than `limit=1001`

What is the fastest way to achive that, ideally without checking all items of the list?
A common way is to use a list comprehension, eg `[i for i in l if i<limit]`, but this way we must check all items of l and compare them with limit. If the limit is in the list, we could use something like `l[:l.index(limit)]` but what if it's not in the list?
Any idea?

Comment: What you are looking for is Binary Search.

Comment: FWIW `l.index` is also `O(n)`, so `l[:l.index(limit)]` and `[i for i in l if i<limit]` have the same complexity

Comment: @ScottHunter Binary search will also not improve the asymptotic complexity as the slicing is still linear. 
But why would you ever turn a `range` object to a list? And if you know the exact bounds, just make another `range`.

Comment: Is the list always sorted and with the same interval between elements, and no missing elements? if so, you can use some basic math formulas (much like how `range` it self is implemented)

Comment: BTW, I hope you are aware that you can slice `range` objects directly

Comment: @schwobaseggl The list could be of any length and step, so it cannot be described as range. My example is simplified

Comment: Well if the initial bounds and step are known, you should be able to directly calculate the index of any value in constant time.

Comment: And one last question, are you worried about time or space complexity? how "big" is this list gonna be? Make sure you are not trying to optimize something that does not require optimization

Comment: @DeepSpace I would be happy to listen to any ideas (both time and space) however my main consern is to not loop through all list items. Ideally a solution that would stop after eg 20 comparisons, while the list could be of length of many zeros. So I think time is the main consern in this case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for this:

```
import bisect
print(l[:bisect.bisect_right(l, 1001)])
```

Comment: Beat me to it! This is fast and `bisect` is underutilized.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to put some comparative timing out there for these two answers.

Given this benchmark:

```
import bisect 
import time 

def f1(l, tgt):
    return bisect.bisect_right(l, tgt)

def f2(l,tgt):
    slice_condition = lambda num: num >= tgt
    try:
        slice_idx = next(idx for idx, num in enumerate(l) if slice_condition(num))
    except StopIteration:
        slice_idx = len(l)
    return slice_idx 

def f3(l,tgt):
    return next((idx for idx, val in enumerate(l) if val>=tgt), len(l))


def cmpthese(funcs, args=(), cnt=10, rate=True, micro=True, deepcopy=True):
    from copy import deepcopy 
    """Generate a Perl style function benchmark"""                   
    def pprint_table(table):
        """Perl style table output"""
        def format_field(field, fmt='{:,.0f}'):
            if type(field) is str: return field
            if type(field) is tuple: return field[1].format(field[0])
            return fmt.format(field)     

        def get_max_col_w(table, index):
            return max([len(format_field(row[index])) for row in table])         

        col_paddings=[get_max_col_w(table, i) for i in range(len(table[0]))]
        for i,row in enumerate(table):
            # left col
            row_tab=[row[0].ljust(col_paddings[0])]
            # rest of the cols
            row_tab+=[format_field(row[j]).rjust(col_paddings[j]) for j in range(1,len(row))]
            print(' '.join(row_tab))                

    results={}
    for i in range(cnt):
        for f in funcs:
            if args:
                local_args=deepcopy(args)
                start=time.perf_counter_ns()
                f(*local_args)
                stop=time.perf_counter_ns()
            results.setdefault(f.__name__, []).append(stop-start)
    results={k:float(sum(v))/len(v) for k,v in results.items()}     
    fastest=sorted(results,key=results.get, reverse=True)
    table=[['']]
    if rate: table[0].append('rate/sec')
    if micro: table[0].append('\u03bcsec/pass')
    table[0].extend(fastest)
    for e in fastest:
        tmp=[e]
        if rate:
            tmp.append('{:,}'.format(int(round(float(cnt)*1000000.0/results[e]))))

        if micro:
            tmp.append('{:,.1f}'.format(results[e]/float(cnt)))

        for x in fastest:
            if x==e: tmp.append('--')
            else: tmp.append('{:.1%}'.format((results[x]-results[e])/results[e]))
        table.append(tmp) 

    pprint_table(table)                    

if __name__=='__main__':
    import sys
    print(sys.version)
    
    small=range(1_000)
    mid=range(100_000)
    large=range(1_000_000)
    cases=(
        ('small, found', small, len(small)//2),
        ('small, not found', small, len(small)),
        ('mid, found', mid, len(mid)//2),
        ('mid, not found', mid, len(mid)),
        ('large, found', large, len(large)//2),
        ('large, not found', large, len(large))
    )
    for txt, x, tgt in cases:
        print(f'\n{txt}:')
        l=list(x)
        args=(l,tgt)
            cmpthese([f1,f2,f3],args)
```

If you run it with small, mid sized and larger lists each with the case of 1) found in the middle or 2) scan all the way to the end, you can see that `bisect` is **substantially faster**. By orders of magnitude.

The benchmark prints on my computer:

```
3.9.1 (default, Jan 30 2021, 15:51:59) 
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)]

small, found:
   rate/sec μsec/pass      f2      f3     f1
f2      182   5,501.4      --  -59.2% -98.8%
f3      445   2,246.9  144.9%      -- -96.9%
f1   14,562      68.7 7911.4% 3172.0%     --

small, not found:
   rate/sec μsec/pass       f2      f3     f1
f2       90  11,053.2       --  -58.8% -99.5%
f3      220   4,555.5   142.6%      -- -98.7%
f1   17,349      57.6 19076.4% 7803.3%     --

mid, found:
   rate/sec μsec/pass        f2       f3     f1
f2        2 561,882.8        --   -57.2% -99.9%
f3        4 240,253.2    133.9%       -- -99.9%
f1    2,942     339.9 165184.0% 70573.1%     --

mid, not found:
   rate/sec   μsec/pass        f2        f3      f1
f2        1 1,119,041.1        --    -58.0% -100.0%
f3        2   469,960.8    138.1%        --  -99.9%
f1    3,804       262.9 425552.8% 178660.3%      --

large, found:
   rate/sec   μsec/pass        f2       f3     f1
f2        0 5,833,734.0        --   -55.3% -99.9%
f3        0 2,605,010.2    123.9%       -- -99.9%
f1      335     2,988.1 195135.5% 87080.9%     --

large, not found:
   rate/sec    μsec/pass        f2        f3      f1
f2        0 11,553,311.3        --    -54.4% -100.0%
f3        0  5,264,216.7    119.5%        -- -100.0%
f1      710      1,408.9 819923.5% 373540.2%      --
```

Comment: Nice comparison. I was wondering where a common solution with loop stands in this, for example the following one:
`m=[l[0]]
n=1
while m[-1]<limit:
    m.append(l[n])
    n+=1
m.pop()`

Comment: Not sure I can compare that directly. Bisect is C based and will be faster than a pure Python method. `.pop()` on lists is also not optimal. If `.pop()` is crucial to your application, consider using a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead for faster insertions / deletions at each end...

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy way to do it in `O(n)` (specifically, `2k` where `k` is the index at which the list needs to be sliced) without relying on binary search would be to search for the index of the first element not meeting the condition, and slice up to that point, using an iterator:

```
slice_condition = lambda num: num >= limit
slice_idx = next((idx for idx, num in enumerate(l) if slice_condition(num)), len(l))
slice = l[:slice_idx]
```

Of course, binary search will find you the `slice_idx` in `O(log(n))` time instead, but slicing is a linear operation anyway so the complexity of the whole unit is still `O(n)`.

Comment: This would be faster if you use the `next(thing, DEFAULT)` rather than a `try` block IMHO

Comment: @dawg I'll be honest, I forgot `next(thing, default)` existed. Thanks for the heads-up, I've edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Your new version throws an error: SyntaxError: `Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`
Your original solution was fast enough though, thanks!